# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed during catkin_make

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to install the Turtlebot3 package in Ros Noetic. After cloning the git, I tried catkin_make. But got the following error -

```
cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make
Base path: /home/md/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/md/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/md/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/md/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/md/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/md/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/md/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_check_deps_Test
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_check_deps_Adc
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Test
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_check_deps_Adc
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_RequestParam
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Log
[  0%] Built target _rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_TopicInfo
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target _turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_Sound
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target _turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_SensorState
[  0%] Built target _turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_VersionInfo
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  1%] Built target image_pub_sub_cpp
[  2%] Built target listener_node
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  2%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  2%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  2%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  3%] Built target utility_lib
[  3%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  4%] Built target read_video_cpp
[  5%] Built target open_copy_cpp
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_AddTwoInts
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciFeedback
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciActionGoal
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciActionFeedback
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_IoTSensor
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciActionResult
[  5%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciAction
[  6%] Built target turtlesim_clean_node
[  6%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciGoal
[  7%] Built target talker_node
[  7%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_py
[  7%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_cpp
[  7%] Built target _ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_check_deps_FibonacciResult
[  7%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_eus
[  7%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_nodejs
[  7%] Built target topic_tools_generate_messages_lisp
[  7%] Built target _ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_check_deps_RectangleArea
[  8%] Built target rosserial_server_lookup
[  8%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3ActionResult
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3Action
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3ActionGoal
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3Goal
[  8%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3Feedback
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3ActionFeedback
[  8%] Built target _turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_check_deps_Turtlebot3Result
[  8%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target nav_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[  8%] Built target gazebo_ros_gencfg
[  8%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  8%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  8%] Built target std_srvs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target gazebo_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  8%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  9%] Built target flat_world_imu_node
[ 10%] Built target usb_cam
[ 12%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_py
[ 12%] Built target turtlebot3_description_xacro_generated_to_devel_space_
[ 13%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_cpp
[ 15%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_eus
[ 16%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 17%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages_lisp
[ 19%] Built target rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_eus
[ 20%] Built target rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_lisp
[ 21%] Built target rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 23%] Built target rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_cpp
[ 26%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 26%] Built target rosserial_mbed_generate_messages_py
[ 28%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 30%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 34%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 34%] Built target rosserial_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 35%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 37%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 39%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 40%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 42%] Built target turtlebot3_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 47%] Built target ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 52%] Built target ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 57%] Built target ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_cpp
[ 58%] Built target laserscan_lib
[ 62%] Built target ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_lisp
[ 68%] Built target ros_essentials_cpp_generate_messages_py
[ 69%] Built target ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_py
[ 70%] Built target ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_cpp
[ 70%] Built target ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_eus
[ 71%] Built target ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_lisp
[ 71%] Built target ros_service_assignment_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 72%] Built target rosserial_server_serial_node
[ 73%] Built target rosserial_server_socket_node
[ 74%] Built target rosserial_server_udp_socket_node
[ 75%] Built target turtlebot3_diagnostics
[ 79%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_cpp
[ 83%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_eus
[ 86%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 90%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_lisp
[ 94%] Built target turtlebot3_example_generate_messages_py
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsdformat9.so.9.5.0', needed by '/home/md/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_gazebo/turtlebot3_drive'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7982: turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_drive.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 95%] Built target turtlebot3_fake_node
[ 95%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages
[ 96%] Built target usb_cam_node
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

I think the problem is in the -

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsdformat9.so.9.5.0', needed by '/home/md/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_gazebo/turtlebot3_drive'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7982: turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/CMakeFiles/turtlebot3_drive.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 95%] Built target turtlebot3_fake_node
[ 95%] Built target rosserial_arduino_generate_messages
[ 96%] Built target usb_cam_node
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393435/invoking-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed-during-catkin_make/) by [Md Shafiqur Rahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/92282/md-shafiqur-rahman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-12-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turtlebot3 can be installed directly from `apt`: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-turtlebot3`.

Check the emanual: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/quick-start/#pc-setup for more information.

For simulations: `sudo apt install ros-noetic-turtlebot3-simulations`

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Md Shafiqur Rahman](https://answers.ros.org/users/92282/md-shafiqur-rahman/) on 2021-12-28**:
Thank you for the suggestion.